# Как в рантайме узнать, использовался ли при компиляции флаг --race?

Tags: golang, race-condition

<sup>(Перевод
[вопроса с ENSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44944959/1892060).)</sup>

Можно ли во время исполнения программы узнать, использовался ли при её
компиляции флаг `--race` для включения детектора состояния
гонки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>(Перевод и обновление
[ответа с ENSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44944960/1892060).)</sup>

При компиляции с флагом `--race` используется
[ограничение сборки](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints)
`race`.  Поэтому можно сделать так:

```golang
// +build race

package pkg

const race = true
```

```golang
// +build !race

package pkg

const race = false
```

Существует также
[предложение](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36477)
добавить этот функционал в пакет `runtime/debug` или
`runtime/race`.